# Git pull suddenly stopped working, troubleshooting "Repository not found"

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

I have been using git to push my local code to a server. I have a local remote that is called "origin" and I have a remote on the server that's called "github". Typically, after committing, I use "git push origin master" to push the local code to github. Next I ssh into the server and use "git pull github master" to pull the github code onto the server. This has been working for a couple of weeks. However, yesterday when I went to pull code to my server from github, I got the following error:

```
python$ git pull github master
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I went back to my local computer and tried a "git push origin master" and  it worked fine. I also tried a "git pull origin master" and it also worked, so clearly the repo exists. So I decided there might be an issue with my remote on the server. I checked the remotes (using "git remote -v") and they match the remotes on my local computer exactly, with the exception of having different remote names. How else should I go about troubleshooting this?

**EDIT**

I know there probably isn't a simple solution to this. I'm fairly new to git and github though, so I'm wondering about the best ways to troubleshoot this. Should I try and destroy my git and run another git init? Are there any other suggestions about what might be the problem?

**EDIT 2**

So now there error has become:

```
python$ git pull github master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I decided to try to initialize a git in another directory, add a new remote and do a pull from the new directory. I ended up with the same result. I'm guessing I can fix this by fixing my keys. My local git and keys are still working, could I possibly grab my keys from my local repo and put them on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had [exactly the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438082/git-fetch-pull-have-stopped-working), and in our case it turned out the problem also had to do with SSH keys - namely, with access rights to the certain GH repo.

Local key was mine and worked fine, while server key were created by some other guy, and when his access to repo was revoked, we couldn't pull the code anymore - and github gives "Repo not found" rather than "You don't have the rights to access this repo".

Answer (score 2):

Github had [some issues with SSH keys](http://arstechnica.com/business/news/2012/03/hacker-commandeers-github-to-prove-vuln-in-ruby.ars) earlier this month, maybe you need to confirm yours?

They should be listed under: https://github.com/settings/ssh

Comment: Right I remember that, I've authorized both of mine, but I also work with a private account and it's possible their keys haven't been confirmed. I'll check on that, but I don't think that's the issue.